# Merged 2 VS Projects - how to change starting .exe file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, project, projects-and-solutions

I had 2 Visual Studio 2013 projects and decided to merge them instead of copying files because I thought it would be more efficient.
After adding Project 2 to Project 1, it turned out that I would need to use circular dependencies and to solve this conflict, I changed the code, added "using Project 1;" to Project 2 namespace and was happy with everything until I hit Start.

The Project obviously starts from Project1.Program.exe (the original one) and I can't find a VS setting to make it start from Project2.Program.exe .

1) I could ask Program1.exe to run Program2.exe, but it's such an ugly solution. 
2) I tried [editing Solution Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z15yzzew.aspx),changing the order in which projects start, but it's still starting from Program1.exe

3) At worst I'll do redo everything, starting with adding Project1 to Project2, but having the same projects already in one Solution begs the question: is there really no other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on Project2 in the solution explorer then select *Set as StartUpProject* :

[image]